Applications of the Petersson trace formula
The Petersson trace formula (for modular forms) is simpler to establish and use than thge Kuznetsov trace formula, but often I see no applications of it. Can it be used to obtain various of the classical applications of the Kuznetsov formula: dimension formula, distribution statements, large sieve inequalities? second moments, etc.?
Why the Eichler-Selberg trace formula, which is also on modular forms, is often used instead to deduce these results? Is the arithmetic side easier to deal with? Do they grasp different information?

See here for your second question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/69715/6518

The Petersson formula and the Kuznetsov formula are perfect counterparts: the former relates Fourier coefficients of holomorphic modular forms to sums of Kloosterman sums, while the latter relates Fourier coefficients of Maass forms to sums of Kloosterman sums. The difference is that we know more about holomorphic modular forms than Maass forms via different methods: dimension formulae via Riemann-Roch, the Ramanujan conjecture via work of Deligne, etc.

But for spectral large sieve results and bounds for moments of $L$-functions, both the Petersson and Kuznetsov formula are used equally well. (I use both in several of my papers, for example.)
